# A special case of the Fermat-Torricelli point in a triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

$\triangle{ABC}$ is an isosceles right triangle; its legs are of length $s = 30\sqrt{5}$ and hypotenuse is of length $30\sqrt{10}$. The Fermat-Torricelli point $P$ must be along the median from the vertex $C$ of the right angle of the triangle.

$\left\vert\overline{CP}\right\vert = x$, and $\left\vert\overline{AP}\right\vert = y = \left\vert\overline{BP}\right\vert$, and
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{m}\angle{APC} = 180 - \theta = \mathrm{m}\angle{BPC} .
\end{equation*}
According to the Law of Cosines,
\begin{equation*}
s^{2} = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy\cos(\theta) .
\end{equation*}
According to the Law of Sines,
\begin{equation*}
y = \frac{s/\sqrt{2}}{\sin(\theta)} .
\end{equation*}
According to the Pythagorean Theorem,
\begin{equation*}
\left(s/\sqrt{2} - x\right)^2 + \left(s/\sqrt{2}\right)^2 = y^2 .
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
y = \sqrt{x^{2} - 30\sqrt{10} \, x + 4500} .
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\left\vert\overline{AP}\right\vert + \left\vert\overline{BP}\right\vert + \left\vert\overline{CP}\right\vert
= x + 2y
= x + 2\sqrt{x^{2} - 30\sqrt{10} \, x + 4500} .
\end{equation*}
The minimum value of this function is
\begin{equation*}
30\sqrt{5\left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right)}
\end{equation*}
at
\begin{equation*}
15\sqrt{10} - 5\sqrt{30} .
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\left\vert\overline{CP}\right\vert = x
= 15\sqrt{10} - 5\sqrt{30} \approx 20.05
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\left\vert\overline{AP}\right\vert = \left\vert\overline{AP}\right\vert
= y
= \frac{1}{2} \left(30\sqrt{5\left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right)}
- \left(15\sqrt{10} - 5\sqrt{30}\right)\right) \approx 54.77 .
\end{equation*}

**My Concern**

I am told that the distances between the vertices and the Fermat-Torricelli Point are natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I've found no errors in your calculations.

---

If we can use the fact that the point $P$ satisfies 
$$\angle{APB}=\angle{BPC}=\angle{CPA}=120^\circ$$
then, we can easily see that 
$$|\overline{CP}|=x=15\sqrt{10}-5\sqrt{30},\qquad|\overline{AP}|=|\overline{BP}|=y=10\sqrt{30}$$
which are the same as what you've got.

Comment: @Adelyn : The fact I've written in the answer is written, for example,  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point#Properties).

Comment: I forgot that all three angles with their vertices at the Fermat-Torricelli point and containing two vertices of the given triangle had measures of $120^{\circ}$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for a formal discussion of the Fermat-Torricelli point?

Comment: I have found "The Convex Coordinates of the Fermat Point" by J.N. Boyd and Lees.

Comment: I would prefer to first see a discussion of its original geometric construction.

Comment: @Adelyn : Have you already seen the part "construction" at [the same wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point#Construction)?

Comment: I have looked at it. There are some statements that are not explained. Why are points $A$, $F$, $B$, and $R$ concyclic?

Comment: @Adelyn: That is aother question. Why don't you ask it as a new question?

Comment: I have asked the question in a separate post.  See "Congruence of angles with vertex at Fermat-Torricelli point in a triangle through two vertices."